# Select rows from data frame based on condition by group

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data frame which is a list of lists - a list of storms, each point of a storm is a row. One column is whether each point in the storm is over land. I'm able to work out which storms have made landfall, however I do not know how to select only those storms, i.e. create a new data frame of only those storms that have made landfall.

This code lets me know whether a storm has made landfall (by grouping by ID it sums the in region column (1 or 0) and if greater than 1 says it's made landfall):

```
land_tracks <- all_tracks[, sum(inregion) > 0, by = ID]
```

Gives me:

```
                  ID    V1
 1: 1987051906_15933  TRUE
 2: 1987060118_16870  TRUE
 3: 1987061306_18015  TRUE
 4: 1987062100_18878  TRUE
 5: 1987062918_19507 FALSE
 6: 1987070512_20168  TRUE
 7: 1987070812_20341  TRUE
 8: 1987071218_20635  TRUE
 9: 1987071412_20762  TRUE
10: 1987071606_20881  TRUE
```

How do I use this to go through all_tracks to find all the rows which match the ID where `V1 == TRUE`?

I regularly have the issue that `land_tracks` has 41 rows, `all_tracks` has 1879 rows, and R raises an issue about recycling.

Comment: You can subset by `V1` and then do something like `all_tracks$ID %in% land_tracks$ID`. I have added the tag `data.table`, since the datasets involved are created and manipulated by functions of that package.

Comment: Thanks, however by using:

land_sel <- land_tracks[which(land_tracks$V1==TRUE),]
sel_tracks <- all_tracks$ID %in% land_sel$ID

sel_tracks has the same length as all_tracks, but has a single column of TRUE/FALSE

I'm clearly missing a step!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can do someting like INNER JOIN between those two tables:

```
merge(all_tracks,land_tracks[which(land_tracks$V1== TRUE)], by = 'ID')
```

Comment: Thanks, that's worked exactly as needed (will need to check the data but looks right at the moment).